# mongorestore command not found, despite having path variables

Tags: database, mongodb

I have installed MongoDB and the Mongo Tools, set the path variables and so on, but I can't use any command out of Mongo Tools. The server works fine though.

This is how I set them in the user variables list:
[user variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHPgD.png)

This is how I set them in the system variables list:
[system variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nIXh.png)

What have I done wrong?

Comment: you have to add the path to executables in `$PATH` variable

Comment: Can you describe what steps you took to install and attempt to connect?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To clarify everything, I installed MongoTools via .msi file and added the files, in which are the executables, to the path variables. As everything is now, the commands don't work, because they can't be found.